# reaction a only first message in "if"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type === 'text' && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() == "channel-2" && message.content === "test")
  {
  message.react("✅")
  }
})
```

this is the code, is there any way for it to react to just the first message? for example: if 5 people send "test" on the same channel, I wanted her to react only to the first, ignoring the other 4

Comment: So the command can only be executed once per channel? And shall this rule persist after a restart of the bot as well?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @NullDev yes, only once per channel, and it doesn't have to be the same rule if the bot is restarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `.off` with the handler when you react:

```
client.on('message', function handler(message) {
    if (message.channel.type === 'text' && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() == "channel-2" && message.content === "test") {
        message.react("✅");
        client.off('message', handler);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it says that "message" is not defined, and when I put it together in client.on('message', function handler({ content, channel, message })  it says "react" is not defined

Comment: Try the code again. There's no React here, so that shouldn't be an issue, I think